# sequence encoding by MultiHeadAttention

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, transformer-model, attention-model

I am trying to encode a sequence of image embeddings to one bigger embedding using MultiHeadAttention. (order doesn't matter)

I want an operation similar to passing a sequence of shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dim)` to an LSTM layer and taking the last hidden_state as an embedding holding all importatnt information about the sequence.. or we may say a sequence embedding.

I want to implement that using attention to get rid of the recurrent behavior..

```
# embeddings: shape(batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dim)
multihead_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(embedding_dim, num_heads)
attn_output, attn_output_weights = multihead_attn(embeddings, embeddings, embeddings)
```

but in this case the attention output will have a shape of `(batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dim)` as well..
should I be doing

```
attn_output = attn_output.mean(1)
```

or what if I pass the query as the `embeddings.mean(1)`.. will that give the intended behavior? will the output simulate a sequence embedding?

```
# embeddings: shape(batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dim)
multihead_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(embedding_dim, num_heads)
seq_emb, attn_output_weights = multihead_attn(embeddings.mean(1), embeddings, embeddings)
```

Comment: did you manage to solve that?